# Erro com xlswrite no Matlab 2016

Tags: matlab

Estou tendo problemas ao salvar dados do Matlab em planilhas do Excel.

Peguei um código de exemplo bem simples:

```
A = [1:257;1:257];

[status message] = xlswrite('teste.xls', A)
```

Mas não funciona. O erro que aparece é:

```
message = 

       message: 'Error: Erro não especificado…'
    identifier: 'MATLAB:COM:E0'
```

Estou com o Office 2016 funcionando perfeito e com o Matlab 2016a. Já desabilitei os suplementos do Excel, executei como adm, criei uma planilha pra ver se ele pelo menos atualizava e nada.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Executei o mesmo código com o MatLab R2015a e Office 365 instalado.
A mensagem de erro foi um pouco diferente e sem uma solução rápida.

```
status = 
     0
message = 
       message: 'The specified data range is invalid or too large to write
       to the specified file format. Try writing ...' 
    identifier: 'MATLAB:xlswrite:SelectDataRange'
```

Já tive outros problemas quando precisei usar o MatLab para exportar dados para outros softwares proprietários. Neste caso, geralmente opto por salvar em CSV e evitar muita dor de cabeça.

Uma solução alternativa para este teu caso seria passar primeiro para *dataset* e depois salvar em formato de planilha. Segue o código que aqui dá certo (exceto pelo cabeçalho adicional que precisa ser eliminado manualmente).

```
A = [1:257;1:257];
ds = mat2dataset(A);
export(ds,'XLSFile','A_dataSet.xlsx')
```

Comment: Eu testei seu código e deu os seguintes erros:

Comment: Error using dataset/export>writeXLSFile/writeXLSVars (line 420)
Error writing dataset variable 'A10' to 'A_dataSet.xlsx':
Error: Erro não especificado

Comment: Error in dataset/export>writeXLSFile (line 409)
        writeXLSVars();

Comment: Error in dataset/export (line 112)
    writeXLSFile(a,xlsfileArg,writevarnames,writeobsnames,otherArgs{:});

Comment: Error in Teste (line 3)
export(ds,'XLSFile','A_dataSet.xlsx')

Comment: Repeti em outro computador, mesmas características de instalação citadas (MatLab R2015a e Office 365). O arquivo de saída  "A_dataSet.xlsx" ocorreu ok. No help do [mat2datset](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mat2dataset.html) tem um alerta: "The dataset data type might be removed in a future release.". Não acredito que seja o caso da tua versão. De qualquer forma, tente executar o exemplo do help [export](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/export-dataset-arrays.html) e veja se ao menos este funciona.